# How to customize android picker button in react native

Tags: android, react-native, styles, picker

I'm trying to implement [picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html) inside my app, everything is ok with IOS, but with android it show the button that open the picker like this :

[image]

and I can't customize the button style ( I want it to be like below ).

[image]

So how to change the button style, I can't find any thing in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native base to customize the button style

Refer the below link
http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.2/customize#themeButton

Comment: Thank's, but I don't want to add the whole native base dependency just for this, I'm looking for a simpler solution.